# Как завернуть несколько кастомных функций в один pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

У меня есть несколько функций для препроцессинга данных и так же модель для обучения.

Я хочу все эти функции использовать внутри одного `pipeline`.
Вот мои функции:

Первая функция:

```
def group_timestamp(dataset, size=False):
    """
        dataset - dataset
        returns: grouped data by timestamp
    """
    if size==False:
        data = dataset.groupby(['time']).mean()
        print('Trades from grouped data: {}'.format(data.shape[0]))
    else:
        if size==True: 
            data_1 = dataset[['time','p']]
            data_2 = dataset[['time','s']]
            data_1 = data_1.groupby(['time']).mean()
            data_2 = data_2.groupby(['time']).sum()
            data = pd.concat([data_1, data_2],axis=1)
    return data
```

Вторая функция:

```
def get_target_size(data, predict_step = 5, trades = 5, limit=5):
    """
        data - dataset for preprocessing
        predict_step - the number of trades in the future where we want to predict the movement
        trades - the number of trades in the past we use for prediction
        return: X, y - attributes and target for models 
    """
    data['step'] = data['p'].shift(predict_step)
    data['step_vol'] = data['s'].shift(predict_step)
    data['step-1'] = data['p'].shift(predict_step+1)
    for i in range(1, trades+1):
        data[i] = data['step-1'].pct_change(i)
    data.dropna(inplace = True) 
    data['y'] = data['p'] - data['step']
    data['y'] = data['y'].apply(lambda s: 1 if s > 0 else 0)
    data['y'] = data.apply(filter_size, limit = limit, axis=1)
    y = data['y']
    y = y[:-trades]
    X = data.drop(['p', 'step', 'step-1', 'y', 'step_vol'], axis=1)
    X = X[:-trades]
    print('Classes distribution:')
    print(data['y'].value_counts())
    print('X shape: {}'.format(X.shape))
    print('y shape: {}'.format(y.shape))
#     print('Examples of X data: {}'.format(X.head()))
#     print('Examples of y data: {}'.format(y.head()))
    return X, y
```

Третья функция:

```
def data_split(X, y, size_valid = 0.15, size_test = 0.1):
    """
        X - attributes
        y - target variable
        size_valid - the size of the validation set. Might be (0...1). Uses for the model evaluation
        size_test - the size of the test set. Might be (0...1). Uses for the model predictions
        return: 
            - X_train_t - dataset for training, attributes
            - y_train_t - dataset for training, target
            - X_train_v - dataset for validation after training, attributes
            - y_train_v - dataset for validation after training, target
            - X_test - dataset for testing the model after training, attributes
            - y_test - dataset for testing the model after training, target
    """
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=size_test)
    X_train_t, X_train_v, y_train_t, y_train_v = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=size_valid)
    print('Train set size: {}, {}'.format(X_train_t.shape, y_train_t.shape))
    print('Validation set size: {}, {}'.format(X_train_v.shape, y_train_v.shape))
    print('Test set size: {}, {}'.format(X_test.shape, y_test.shape))
    return (X_train_t, y_train_t, X_train_v, y_train_v, X_test, y_test)
```

Обучение модели:

```
clf = LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Сейчас я использую эти функции друг за другом, вызывая следующую функцию, после предыдущей.

Как эти 3 функции завернуть в один `pipeline`? 
Нужно ли для этого изменять функции, описанные выше?
Я хочу иметь что-то вроде:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('group_time', group_timestamp),
    ('get_target', get_target_size),
    ('split', data_split),
    ('clf',LGBMClassifier)])

    pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы задали слишком обширный вопрос. Попробую ответить на некоторые моменты...

1. разделение на обучающую и тестовую выборку обычно делается до / вне pipeline
2. в функции `get_target_size()` - вы создаете и возвращаете `y` кроме `X`. Сорее всего это не будет работать потому, что метод `.fit()` обычно возвращает `self`, а метод `.fit_transform()` обычно возвращает трансформированный `X`. Ни один из них не возвращает `y`, соответственно все манипуляции с `y` - не сохраняются в `pipeline`, т.е. теряются

Если подытожить, то получается что сначала вам надо проделать все манипуляции над целевым столбцом `y`, потом разделить данные на обучающую и тестовую выборки и только потом строить `pipeline`